# Is there any generalization of Lebesgue's number lemma?

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-topology

I have encountered a problem in learning algebra-topology these days. There is a basic and important result about the fundamental group: the fundamental group of $S^1$ is $\mathbb{Z}$. The proof of this conclusion uses the **path lifting lemma** and **homotopy lifting lemma**, and the proof of these two lemmas uses another lemma called **Lebesgue's number lemma**.

**Lebesgue's number lemma**:
If the metric space $(X,d)$ is compact and an open cover of $X$ is given, then there exists a number $\delta>0$ such that every subset of $X$ having diameter less than $\delta$ is contained in some member of the cover.
Such a number $\delta$ is called a Lebesgue number of this cover. The notion of a **Lebesgue number** itself is useful in other applications as well.

What I want to ask is: **does this lemma have generalization form in more general space, such as compact non-metric space?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but we need an additional structure to have a measure for the "diameter" of a set. A metric on $X$ does this very nicely. A well-known generalization of the concept of a metric space is that of *uniform space*. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space. I shall not go into the details of the definition here, see the Wikipedia article or consult a textbook. The key concept is that of an *entourage of the diagonal*. A *uniform structure* $\mathcal U$ on a set $X$ is a collection of such entourages subject to suitable axioms. If $(x,y) \in V \in \mathcal U$, we symbolically write $\lvert x - y \rvert < V$. If $M \subset X$ has the property $M \times M \subset V$, we write $\text{diam} M < V$. This means that for all $x,y \in M$ we have $\lvert x - y \rvert < V$.

Here are some basic facts.

1. Each uniform structure on a set $X$ induces a unique topology on $X$. A subset $G \subset X$ is open in this topology if each $x \in G$ admits an entourage $V$ such that the set $B(x,V) = \{ y \in X \mid \lvert x -y \rvert < V \} = \{ y \in X \mid (x,y) \in V \}$ of $x$ is contained in $G$. Note that $B(x,V)$ is not necessarily *open* in $X$, but it is easy to see that it contains an open neighborhood of $x$. Thus $B(x,V)$ can legitimately be called the $V$-neighborhood of $x$.
2. Each metric $d$ on $X$ induces a natural uniform structure on $X$. A basis for this uniform structure is given by the sets $V_\varepsilon = \{ (x,y) \in X \times X \mid d(x,y) < \varepsilon \}$. Thus by definition $\lvert x - y \rvert < V_\varepsilon$ is equivalent to $d(x,y)  < \varepsilon$ and $\text{diam} M < V_\varepsilon$ means that $d(x,y)  < \varepsilon$ for all $x,y \in M$.
3. Each compact Hausdorff space has a unique uniform structure inducing its topology. A basis for this uniform structure is given by the open neighborhoods of the diagonal in the space $X \times X$ with the product topology.

Let us now prove

Let $X$ be a compact uniform space. Then each open cover $\mathfrak U$ of $X$ admits an entourage $V$ such that each $M \subset X$ with $\text{diam} M < V$ is contained in a member of $\mathfrak U$.

To see this, note that for each $x \in X$ there exists an entourage $V_x$ such that the $V_x$-neighborhood $B(x,V_x)$ of $x$ is contained in some member of $\mathfrak U$. Choose an entourage $W_x$ such that $W_x \circ W_x = \{ (x,y) \in X \times X \mid \ \exists z \in X : (x,z),(z,y) \in W_x \} \subset V_x$. Since $X$ is compact, there exist finitely many $x_i$ such that $\bigcup_i B(x_i,W_{x_i}) = X$. Then $W = \bigcap W_{x_i}$ is an entourage. Now let $\text{diam} M < W$ and $\xi \in M$. We have $\xi \in B(x_i,W_{x_i})$ for some $i$, i.e. $(x_i,\xi) \in W_{x_i}$. For $x  \in M$ we have $(\xi,x) \in W \subset W_{x_i}$, thus $(x_i,x) \in W_{x_i} \circ W_{x_i} \subset V_{x_i}$ which means $x \in B(x_i,V_{x_i})$. Therefore $M \subset B(x_i,V_{x_i})$. The latter is contained in some member of $\mathfrak U$.

Comment: Do you apply compactness to the open cover $\{\operatorname{int}(B(x, W_x)) \mid x\in X\}$?

Comment: @beroal Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Can you say which book this proof comes from? All proofs I saw argue from contradiction, which is ugly. So that book may be interesting.

Comment: @beroal I can't remember that I used a book.